# System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта - С#

Tags: c#

делаю небольшой месенджер на C#, для изучения net.sockets;
Сделал так, чтобы принимание сообщений было ассинхронным, и во время их получения можно было что-то писать.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        //static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        static string str;
        static Socket client;
        static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 25565));
            socket.Listen(5);
            Socket client = socket.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("New User!!!");
            while (true)
            {
                MainAsync();
                TakeMessage();
            }

        }
        private static async Task TakeMessage() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            Task.Run(() =>  client.Receive(buffer)); //Тут ошибка
            Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)));
        }
        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            Task.Run(() => str = Console.ReadLine());
            Task.Run(()=> command(str));

        }
        private static async Task NewUser()
        {
            //Task.Run(()=>)
        }
        private static void command(string com){
            if(com == "close")
            {
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но в 32ой строке появляется ошибка "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
"

Comment: Внутри `Main` вы определеяете _локальную_ переменную `client`.

Comment: `static Socket client;`  вы объявили, а где инициализация?

Comment: А зачем вы запускаете Task-и параллельно? У вас получается в buffer может ещё ничего нет, а второй Task уже что-то печатает из него,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас не присвоена переменная `client`. Как я понял, вам нужно 2 сокета, один для отправки сообщений, второй для приема. Так вот, один вы инициализировали, а второй нет. (Кстати, а точно нужно два?)

В то же время Microsoft рекомендует [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=netframework-4.8):

> Если вы создаете относительно простое приложение, не требующее максимальной производительности, рассмотрите возможность использования [`TcpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8), [`TcpListener`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8) и [`UdpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netframework-4.8). Эти классы предоставляют более простой и удобный интерфейс для взаимодействия с `Socket`.

Но это только часть беды. Вы странно используете асинхронность, которая вам не особо и нужна. Вам базово нужно просто 2 потока, один на прием сообщиний, второй на передачу, и чтобы они работали одновременно.

Я написал короткий пример, убрав весь сетевой код, и оставил только скелет для демонстрации шаблона с двумя одновременно работающими задачами.

Для управления прерыванием задач я буду использовать `CancellationToken`. Изучите его, он много где может пригодиться. Его так же можно передавать в разного рода стандартные асинхронные методы.

```csharp
// асинхронный Main, обратите внимание
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        List<Task> loops = new List<Task>();
        loops.Add(Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessageLoop(cts)));
        loops.Add(Task.Run(() => SendMessageLoop(cts)));
        await Task.WhenAll(loops);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Shutdown");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void ReceiveMessageLoop(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReceiveMessageLoop");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("ReceiveMessageLoop exit");
}

private static void SendMessageLoop(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Command: ");
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
        if (command == "exit")
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
        if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("SendMessageLoop exit");
}
```

А вот доказательство, что асинхронность не особо и нужна, разницы в поведении приложения не будет.

```csharp
// обычный синхронный Main
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        List<Task> loops = new List<Task>();
        loops.Add(Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessageLoop(cts)));
        loops.Add(Task.Run(() => SendMessageLoop(cts)));
        Task.WaitAll(loops.ToArray());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Shutdown");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

А по реализации сетевой части с помощью `Socket`, если вам уж так очень хочется, да еще и с асинхронностью, смотрите примеры в документации: [Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example), [Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).

**Еще на заметку:** `async` без `await` внутри ни имеет никакого смысла и не дает никакого эффекта, а обратное вообще невозможно. :)